# MySQL JOIN Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, join

I've taken a look at the possible solutions around S.O and my query is still not working fine.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT `messages`.`from_id`, 
  `messages`.`to_id`, 
  `messages`.`message` 
FROM `messages`
JOIN 
(
  SELECT `users`.`profile_pic` 
  FROM `users` AS `from_pic` 
  WHERE `users`.`id` = `from_id`
)  
  ON `users`.`id` = `messages`.`from_id` 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT `users`.`profile_pic` 
  FROM `users` AS `to_pic` 
  WHERE `users`.`id` = `to_id`
)  
  ON `users`.`id` = `messages`.`to_id` 
WHERE  `messages`.`from_id` = 23 
  AND `messages`.`to_id` = 24 
ORDER BY `date_sent` DESC;
```

**Table `users`**

```
id | profile_pic | name
```

**Table `messages`**

```
message_id | from_id | to_id | message
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using subqueries, you need to provide an alias on them:

```
SELECT 
  `messages`.`from_id`, 
  `messages`.`to_id`, 
  `messages`.`message` 
FROM `messages`
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    `from_pic`.`id`, 
    `from_pic`.`profile_pic` 
  FROM `users` AS `from_pic` 
)  u1 --- alias
  ON u1.`id` = `messages`.`from_id` 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    `to_pic`.`id`,
    `to_pic`.`profile_pic` 
  FROM `users` AS `to_pic` 
)  u2 ---- alias
  ON u2.`id` = `messages`.`to_id` 
WHERE  `messages`.`from_id` = 23 
  AND `messages`.`to_id` = 24 
ORDER BY `date_sent` DESC;
```

This could also be written without subqueries:

```
SELECT 
  `messages`.`from_id`, 
  `messages`.`to_id`, 
  `messages`.`message` 
FROM `messages`
JOIN `users` AS `from_pic` 
  ON `from_pic` = `messages`.`from_id` 
JOIN `users` AS `to_pic` 
  ON `to_pic`.`id` = `messages`.`to_id` 
WHERE  `messages`.`from_id` = 23 
  AND `messages`.`to_id` = 24 
ORDER BY `date_sent` DESC;
```

Comment: I see. I tried this out before but I was getting this error, so I'm not sure what is wrong: `#1054 - Unknown column 'users.profile_pic' in 'field list'
`

Comment: @nTuply See my edit, you've provided aliases inside of your subquery for the `users` table, you need to reference that alias in there.

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'from_id' in 'where clause'` The errors are crazy. Do you think I should post my table design?

Comment: @nTuply That would probably help. Does `users` have a `from_id` column?

Comment: Added the tables. No, `users` don't have it. `messages` have the `from_id` and `to_id` which I'm trying to join with `users` to get the profile pic of each user

Comment: @nTuply I made another edit. Your subqueries shouldn't reference columns not in that table, that's what the join condition is for.  It doesn't seem like you need the subqueries, so I also gave a version without them.

Answer (score -1):

You need to move your `from_pick` and `to_pic` aliases out of the subqueries they are not needed in, and use them accordingly in your join conditions, like so:

```
SELECT `messages`.`from_id`, 
  `messages`.`to_id`, 
  `messages`.`message` 
FROM `messages`
JOIN 
(
  SELECT `users`.`profile_pic` 
  FROM `users`
  WHERE `users`.`id` = `from_id`
) AS `from_pic` 
  ON `from_pic`.`id` = `messages`.`from_id` 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT `users`.`profile_pic` 
  FROM `users` 
  WHERE `users`.`id` = `to_id`
)  AS `to_pic` 
  ON `to_pic`.`id` = `messages`.`to_id` 
WHERE  `messages`.`from_id` = 23 
  AND `messages`.`to_id` = 24 
ORDER BY `date_sent` DESC;
```

Better yet, you don't even actually need subqueries:

```
SELECT `messages`.`from_id`, 
  `messages`.`to_id`, 
  `messages`.`message` 
FROM `messages`
JOIN `users` AS `from_pic` ON `from_pic`.`id` = `messages`.`from_id` 
JOIN `users` AS `to_pic` ON `to_pic`.`id` = `messages`.`from_id` 
WHERE  `messages`.`from_id` = 23 
  AND `messages`.`to_id` = 24 
ORDER BY `date_sent` DESC;
```

Comment: Ouch. If you're going to down vote, you should at least say what the problem with the answer is.